# How to know my processor is 32 or 64 bits in C#?

Tags: c#

How to know my processor is 32 or 64 bits in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class [`Win32_Processor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28VS.85%29.aspx) using [`System.Management.ManagementObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx):

```
ManagementObject mo;
mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
ushort i = (ushort)mo["Architecture"];

switch (i)
{
case 0:
  return "32 Bit";
  break;
case 9:
  return "64 Bit";
  break;
}
```

Take a look at [the MSDN Library description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28VS.85%29.aspx#properties) for other processor codes.

A problem with this is that the user, who is running the program, needs privileges for viewing the WMI.

Comment: I can query the Win32_Processor class (from PowerShell) just fine without administrative privileges. Also you could just query the AddressWidth/DataWidth instead of architecture because architecture 6 (Itanium) would be 64 bits too. Don't assume there's only x86 and x86_64 out there.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using .NET 4.0 or newer, there is a built-in property [`System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) to give you this information.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to natively check in C# is:

```
var size = IntPtr.Size;
```

size will equal either 4 or 8 but the bigger question is why do you need to know?

Comment: That doesn't tell you what kind of processor it is, only what the current application is run as.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the CPU (and more) information from the registry:

```
HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor
```

Has 1 or more subkeys (one for each core) called 0, 1, 2 etc. Each subkey contains information on the core including the Identifier which contains either x86 or some 64 bit in text, including processor family and model.

Comment: This is correct, but only on windows machines.  I don't think this will work for Silverlight, Phone 7 apps, or apps running on mono/linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to find out if the current application is running as a 32-bit application or a 64-bit application, just use the `IntPtr.Size` property.

```
int bits = IntPtr.Size * 8;
```

To find out information about the actual processor is harder. [Here is a library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=13) that gets some information, but the page doesn't tell if it gets that specific information. You can [get some information from the registry](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Windows/RetrievetheCPUTypeandSpeedfromtheRegistry.htm), I haven't checked how much information there is.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use P/Invoke to call [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340(VS.85).aspx) and get a SystemInfo structure.

Another solution looks like this:

```
isWow64 = false;
if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 5 && 
     System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1)
{
     var processHandle = GetProcessHandle((uint)
          System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
     bool retVal;
     if (!NativeMethods.IsWow64Process(processHandle, out retVal))
     {
     throw (new Win32Exception());
     }
     isWow64 = retVal;
}
```

Alternative solution (but not recommended) :)

```
public bool Is64bitOS
{
    get
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)")
               != null;
    }
}

public string ProgramFilesX86
{
    get
    {
        string programFiles =
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)");
        if (programFiles == null)
        {
            programFiles = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
                           "ProgramFiles");
        }

        return programFiles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Query the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx) class via WMI

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr hProcess, [Out] out bool lpSystemInfo);

        public static bool Is64Bit()
        {
            bool retVal;

            IsWow64Process(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out retVal);

            return retVal;
        }
```